# Можно ли сделать сайт на чистом html+css+javascript+PHP?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я новичок в веб разработке.
Можно ли сделать сайт на чистом html+css+javascript без фреймворков? 
или это уже прошлое? 
Долго ли изучать django или Laravel?

Comment: Данный вопрос является совсем непонятным, неполным, слишком общим, основанным на личном мнении или не относится к теме Stack Overflow на русском как описано в Справке и вряд ли может быть улучшен правками.

Comment: Можно, но не целесообразно. Сайт сайту рознь, но если без наворотов то Yii2 или тот же Laravel доступен на русском и есть видеокурсы. Да за неделю базовые вещи, легко.

Comment: Можно, делайте.

Comment: фреймворк нужен просто для удобства, те же фреймворки написаны на "чистых" html css js php и тд

Comment: Конечно можно, особенно для новичков рекомендуется делать чисто на HTML+CSS+JS+PHP. Фреймфорки это просто набор готовых паттернов. А на чистом php всё это будете делать с нуля если не паттерны то просто процедурным методом.

Comment: имхо, смотря что это за сайт, если это онлайн-казино или геоинформационная система, вряд ли какой либо фреймворк сильно облегчит написание кода, а если это обычная страничка с обычными компонентами вроде форума или интернет магазина - вполне

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на первый вопрос: да можно.

Ответ на второй вопрос: Это не прошлое! Есть много сайтов который написан просто HTML+CSS+JS+PHP

Ответ на третий вопрос: Это уже зависит от вашей знаний по веб программированию. Я имею ввиду, если вы знаете POST-GET запросы, Сессии, Куки и т.д., то легче и быстрее изучаете.

Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо. Большое. Доходчиво обьяснили новичку.

Answer (score 1):

В первую очередь фреймворки предназначены для облегчения работы и уменьшения ее объема, они реализуют фундаментальный функционал вроде шабонизаторов, функций и др. Они создаются чтобы не изобретать велосипеды

Время затраченное на изучение какого либо фреймворка напрямую зависит от ваших навыков и умений читать документацию, особенно на английском языке, ну и естественно от ваших знаний в данной области, хотя в случае с фреймворками входной порог все же ниже.

Никто не мешает написать сайт с нуля, но на это колоссально больше времени чем воспользоваться каким либо даже небольшим фреймворком, например в случае с FrontEnd разработкой, это может быть [**Twitter Bootstrap**](https://getbootstrap.com/), который уже предоставляет различные готовые сетки, оформление уведомление/input'ов и других элементов. Или же **[JQuery](https://jquery.com/)** который используют наверное везде.

Answer (score 0):

Когда то давно реализовывал свою конструкцию MVC, но это у же в прошлом. В наше время намного облегчают работу различные фреймворки, но для этого я думаю изначально нужно углубиться в языки программирования, понять логику.

Изначально работал на фреймворке **Yii2**, а теперь на **Laravel**. Тут уж нечего говорить по сравнению своим "чистым" кодом, но выделю следующее:

- Скорость работы
- Защита
- Продуманная логика
- Мануалы и поддержка
- Востребованность
- Upgrade, особенно благодаря множеству готовых пакетов